# How to get the last inserted record from table in SQL / Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have table that contains a column `User_ID nvarchar(17)` and I need to get the last inserted value from the `User_ID` column

Column values would be like

```
ABCDEF0001  -- first inserted value
ABCDEF0301  -- third inserted value
BCDEF0002  -- second inserted value
BEF0901  -- last inserted value
CDEF0451   -- 4th inserted value
```

I want output of the above is `BEF0901`.

Comment: You have `LastUpdatedTime` or `CreationTime` column? else what is the algorithm to find who is added last ?

Comment: You must have createddatetime or any incremental ID column in your table to achieve last inserted userID

Comment: **Show us** how you're inserting the data! Where and how do you determine the new value for `User_ID` ?? And what **database** is this for? SQL is just the **query language** (not the database system)

Comment: user_id is primary key, this is sql server 2008. am inserting the values based on last inserted row example the last inserted user_id is CDEF00234 then the next inserting user_id is like ABCD00235, DEFG00236...

Comment: Design decisions... Meaningful primary key values is an anti pattern. If "last inserted entity" has any bearing on business logic you should use values that are meant to be visible to the business, like insert date-times. Currently, it seems you can only parse the numeric part and sort by it, very inefficient index-wise.

Comment: MS Sql-Server "Change Data Capture" feature should be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way of solution that 
1. we can add identity column on the table and fetch the data based on this identity column and do what ever you want.
2. By using ROWNUMBER also we can get the rows and do the manipulation according to your requirement.
3. We can add datetime column to the table and based on the datetime fetch the data and do the manipulation according to your requirement.

If Any one have any solution apart from the above, please share it across.